# Is there a way in SQL to combine pairs through reflexive property?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table (team1, team2, score).

Data:

```
A    B    40

B    A    20
```

How do I combine them together so that my final result is

```
A    B    60
```

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEAST/GREATEST`:

```
SELECT LEAST(team1, team2) AS team1, GREATEST(team1, team2) AS team2, SUM(score) AS score
FROM tab
GROUP BY LEAST(team1, team2), GREATEST(team1, team2)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c079f28564e7b4c67fb4128652c88038)**

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support `least()`/`greatest()` as Lukasz suggests.  The more generic solution uses `case`:

```
select (case when team1 < team2 then team1 else team2 end) as team1,
       (case when team1 < team2 then team2 else team1 end) as team2,
       sum(score)
from t
group by (case when team1 < team2 then team1 else team2 end),
         (case when team1 < team2 then team2 else team1 end);
```

If all pairs are in the data in both directions, then is fine.  However, if some pairs are in only one direction, then you might get results that are not in the original data.  That is:

```
team1     team2     score
  6         3         10
```

would be transformed to:

```
team1     team2     score
  3         6        10
```

Where the pair is not in the original data.

If this is undesirable, you can use:

```
select team1, team2, sum(score)
from ((select team1, team2, score
       from t
       where team1 <= team2 
      ) union all
      (select team2, team1 score
       from t
       where team2 < team1 and
             not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.team1 = t.team2 and t2.team2 = t.team1
                        )
      )
     ) t
group by team1, team2;
```